# How much can you detect undefined behaviour using testing

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

I hope this question fits this site.
You may know you can't detect [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in C using compilers - and some tools (static analysis) can help you detect it.
My question is more empirical - I know exact solution cant' exist.
Question:

- Say one developed software and performed *intensive testing of the application for several days* and no issues found, **how much** can he be sure there is no undefined behaviour constructs used in his application?
- Consider same situation as above and that the software the programmer developed has been deployed to a company who is using it *for several months and no issues have been reported*. In practice, **how much** can one be sure in such case the there is no Undefined behaviour in software?

PS. Extra: If there is undefined behaviour in function A() in program, can program behave well when it reaches A() and malfunction when it reaches function B() - which has no problems?

Comment: interesting... consider a threaded program - how much can you test to prove the threads do not corrupt each others state as such a bug would never be deterministic?

Comment: @gbjbaanb: don't know. and don't know also if threads==UB in this context of testing

Answer (score 4):

In both cases, testing will provide 0% additional certainty that no undefined behavior constructs are used in the application. Testing inherently does not have the ability to detect undefined behavior. Testing tests for wrong behavior. Undefined is very different from wrong.

"Undefined behavior constructs" are often deterministic (meaning we can know what happens, and always the same thing happens) if run in a *well specified environment*. Many types of undefined behavior work similar to the following: The program writes to a variable that it shouldn't write to, that variable is never read afterwards, and the program works correctly. From the perspective of the external test, there is no issue. Undefined behavior that gives a wrong result also exists, but is usually detected and fixed quickly, because the wrong result makes it easy to spot.

Such "harmless" undefined behavior is still seriously dangerous, because it relies on the aforementioned *well specified environment*. Over the lifetime of a program, there are often some minor and some major changes to that *well specified environment*. Some of these changes are compiler changes, OS updates, change of CPU architecture (the results of going from multi-threaded single core to multi-threaded multi-core were particularly nasty).

Comment: I would expect 0% as you say to be under estimation

Comment: Okay so let's say it doesn't detect 100% of the cases, right? If it detects 95% though isn't that better than 0%? Just because it can't detect every single case doesn't mean it's not valuable. And if it does detect some (and compilers can do this so I know it's not true to say that they detect none) then once those are fixed there are fewer instances of UB.

Answer (score 4):

Many seemingly reasonable things in C (and C++) actually have undefined behavior and this is a common source of bugs in programs.

Moreover there is no good way to determine whether a large scale application is free of undefined behavior and thus not susceptible to breaking in the future.

Some techniques like [Undefined Behavior Coverage](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/388) (see also the [Klee project](http://klee.github.io/) that uses symbolic analysis to *try every possible path*) have been proposed but they don't quantify the "security level".

There are many good tools:

- [Valgrind memcheck](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#memcheck) (can't find things the optimizer removes)
- `clang -fcatch-undefined-behavior` that inserts **runtime** checks to find violations
- [c-semantic-tools](http://code.google.com/p/c-semantics/) (see [An Executable Semantics For C Is Useful](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/523) for an introduction)
- [clang static analizer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/)
- ...

but nothing that gives full confidence that your code won't break in the future (or at least a security index).

The best you can do is [be very careful](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548/Surviving-the-Release-Version), use good tools and hope for the best.

Some other interesting / related link are:

- [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)  (especially part 2 and 3)
- [A C++ implementation that detects undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7237963/3235496)

Comment: yeah but talk here is about chances I'd think it is reasonable as more you test belief that program is free of UB increases (with some proportion even say 0.01)

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to say. Like any other bug, it can work for years, until one day your application starts crashing, after aparently innocent change.

One such example is writing buffer after it's end.

That is why the software needs to be tested at various levels (unit, functional, integration, etc), checked with static analisys tools, and those tests should be executed with memory checkers (like valgrind, when possible). Then you can say that you extended your safety net, and that the probability for bug (including undefined behaviours) is reduced.

---

> If there is undefined behaviour in function A() in program, can program behave well when it reaches A() and malfunction when it reaches function B() - which has no problems?

With undefined behaviour anything is possible, including the [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

As I said above, even a simple change can cause UB to misbehave in very bad ways. To make things worse, it doesn't have to trigger the same behaviour every time. It can appear to work in 99 execution, and crash your application
on the 100th.

Comment: writing past buffer is *potential* undefined behaviour let's call it - if the input is small and there is no writing past the buffer all is OK. I am however refering to cases which are 100% undefined behaviour and revealing them throughout time and testing?

Comment: @user30020 It is not a *potential undefine behaviour* - it is an undefined behaviour. What exactly do you have on your mind?

Comment: I mean doing `memcpy(dest,src,len)` is not undefined behaviour if all three parameters are proper, enough `len` etc. But if user supplies `len` larger then `dest` size - this is undefined behaviour. I referred to cases which are 100% UB. (Not like this example)

Comment: @user30020 So, what exactly do you ask?

Comment: You buffer writing example is not what I referred to because that is a *potential* undefined behaviour. My question is asked in the context when there are 100% undefined behaviour cases in code. And how testing can reveal them ... ?

Comment: @user30020 The answer is the same : with UB anything can happen. BTW I am not sure what you meant with "potential undefined behaviour".

Comment: `memcpy(dest,src,len)` is not undefined behaviour if all three parameters are correct - it is UB if user say supplies third parameter which is too long(assuming third parameter comes from user). This is potential because if user doesn't supply wrong parameter there is no undefined behaviour. int i; printf("%d",i); is 100% UB - and I am asking about that - how much testing can reveal UBs like the latter?

Comment: The user who no longer is here was sorely missing the point. I believe what they were saying is that some functions **can function properly provided that the call has valid parameters/conditions**. But that is **not the same thing as 'writing past a buffer'**: that is always undefined because the standard says so.